# Build divs JS functions included in JS or jQuery from ajax & php data

Tags: javascript, jquery

If a user checks a form checkbox I want to create a new div. Dynamic data is loaded from ajax and php. I am asking how to create it with JS or jQuery. A simplified version will look something like

```
<div id="ajaxSRC1" class="CLASS">
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" onmouseover="return myFunction('ajaxSRC5', 'ajaxSRC6')">
      <img src="ajaxSRC2" width="ajaxSRC3" height="ajaxSRC4" alt="..." />
   </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Nothing, I've read how to handle id, class, width, height but I don't know what to do with an onmouseover function. I was thinking about creating this in server side, maybe better, creating a single var with the output buffer of the entire code and passing it to JS. Anyway I don't know how to handle it.

Comment: Could you post your ajax code?

Comment: Yes. It is very simple.
`$.ajax({`
    `type: 'post',`
    `url: 'test.php?id=52454',`
    `dataType: 'json',`
    `success: function(obj) {`
       `alert(obj.ajaxSRC1); // this var is displayed, same the others `
     `}`
`});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Inside the checkbox click handler:

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'post',
    url : 'test.php?id=52454',
    dataType : 'json',
    success : function (obj) {

        //construct and create the element
        var content = $('<div id="' + obj.ajaxSRC1 + '" class="CLASS">'
                    + '<a href="#">'
                    + '<img src="'+obj.ajaxSRC2+'" width="'+obj.ajaxSRC3+'" height="'+obj.ajaxSRC4+'" alt="..." />'
                    + '</a></div>');

        // bind mouseover event to the anchor tag
        content.find('a').mouseover(function() {
            myFunction(obj.ajaxSRC5, obj.ajaxSRC6);
            return false; // alternative to href="javascript:void(0)"
        });

        // append the newly created div to DOM
        divContainer.append(content);

    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I am working on it. Is it possible to build the div in server and pass it to JS to append the div. I made a try but I could not get the buffer var. Maybe it need some kind of serialization.

Comment: I finally used .on() to handle events. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

first, don't use inline JS, use external script file
second, div can be created with jquery like so

```
$('<div id="dataContainer" />');
```

just add this on event, for example:

```
$('#checkbox').click(function(){
  $('<div id="dataContainer" />').html(ajaxSRC5);
});
```